# Read from file after end-of-file is reached

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, eof, seekg

I have a function named `readNextString(ifstream &file , char* &pBuffer)` which extracts the next string from a file, until `','` or `'\n'` is reached, removes whitespace at the beginning and at the end of the string, saves the rest in pBuffer and returns true if everything worked fine - false otherwise. Everything works until the end-of-file is reached. When the `eof` flag is set I can't move my get pointer.
I've tried this:

```
if(file.eof())
{
   file.clear();
   file.seekg(0 , ios::end)
}
```

...and then remove whitespaces at the end of the string. This almost helped. The function extracts the string without the spaces but I get an infinite loop.

My actual question is: How can I check if the next char is `EOF`, and if I can't - is there any alternative way to do this?

Here is my actual function:

```
bool readNextString(ifstream &file , char* &pBuffer)
{
    if(file.eof()){
        return false;
    }
    for(; file.good() && isWhitespace(file.peek()) && !file.eof() ; file.seekg(1 , ios::cur))
        ;
    if(file.eof()){
        cout << "The file is empty.\n";
        return false;
    }else{
        streamoff startPos = file.tellg();
        cout << "startPos : " << startPos << endl;
        for(;file.good() && file.peek()!='\n' && file.peek()!=',' && file.peek()!= EOF; file.seekg(1 , ios::cur))
            ;
        streamoff A = file.tellg();
        cout << "A : " << A << endl;
        file.seekg(-1 , ios::cur);
        for(;file.good() && isWhitespace(file.peek()) ; file.seekg(-1 , ios::cur))
            ;
        file.seekg(2 , ios::cur);
        streamoff endPos = file.tellg();
        cout << "endPos : " << endPos << endl;
        pBuffer = new char[endPos-startPos];
        if(pBuffer)
        {
            file.seekg(startPos , ios::beg);
            file.get(pBuffer , endPos-startPos , ',' || '\n');
            for(;file.good() && file.peek()!='\n' && file.peek()!=',' && file.peek()!= EOF; file.seekg(1 , ios::cur))
                ;
            file.seekg(2 , ios::cur);
            streamoff temp = file.tellg();
            cout << "temp : " << temp << endl;
            return true;
        }else{
            cout << "Error! Not enough memory to complete the task.\nPlease close some applications and try again.\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's one place where I call it:

```
void printCities()
{
    ifstream city ;
    city.open("cities.txt", fstream::in);
    if(city.is_open())
    {
        char *currCity;
        int counter = 1;
        while(readNextString(city , currCity))
        {
            cout << counter++ << ". " << currCity << endl;
            delete[] currCity;
            currCity = NULL;
        }
        if(city.eof())
            cout << "There are no cities added.\n";
        city.close();
    }else
        cout << "Error by opening 'cities.txt'.Make sure that the file exist and try again.\n";
}
```

Hope I was clear enough. If you find some other mistakes or possible errors I'll be glad to hear it and learn from it.

Comment: FYI you _really_ don't want to parse strings out of a file like this. Either read the entire file into a buffer or read large chunks at a time into a buffer and parse it in memory. Don't do a million reads. It's slow. And for this, actually is more complicated.

Comment: @Dave Reading character by character isn't necessarily slow; the `istream` does the buffering.  Using seek _is_ slow, however; in a lot of implementations, seek will cause the buffer to be lost, and two system calls per character.  (It doesn't have to, but seeks within a buffer should be rare enough that the library doesn't optimize them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.I did it otherwise! getline() for the WIN !  :D
So this is my code (this time is much more readable) :

```
bool readNextString(ifstream &file , char pBuffer[] )
{
    while(isWhitespace(file.peek()) && !file.eof())
        file.ignore(1);
    if(!file.eof())
    {
        streamoff start = file.tellg();
        stringstream toComma;
        if(file.getline(pBuffer , 200 , ','))
        {
            toComma << pBuffer;
            toComma.getline(pBuffer ,200, '\n');
            int i=strlen(pBuffer)-1;
            for(; isWhitespace(pBuffer[i]) ;i--)
                ;
            pBuffer[i+1] = '\0';
            file.clear();
            file.seekg(start + strlen(pBuffer) , file.beg);
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've made some changes in my other function too:

```
void printCities()
{
    ifstream city ;
    city.open("cities.txt", fstream::in);
    if(city.is_open())
    {
        if(!isEmpty(city))
        {
            char currCity[200];
            int counter = 1;
            while(readNextString(city , currCity) && counter < 10)
                cout << counter++ << ". " << currCity << endl;
        }else
            cout << "There are no cities added.\n";
        city.close();
    }else
        cout << "Error by opening 'cities.txt'.Make sure that the file exist and try again.\n";
}
```

The function `isEmpty(ifstream &file)` returns true if the file is empty and false otherwise.

Thanks to all for help ! 
Best regards !

Answer (score 3):

> How can I check if the next char is EOF?

Like this

```
if (file.peek() == EOF)
{
    // next char is EOF
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah,that is in my code ,but i doesn't work properly.
The problem appear at the second for loop when I'm trying to find out where is the next ',' , '\n' or in this case EOF.When I check the position of get pointer (tellg) , in my code i save it as 'A' , and it tells that the position is -1... :(

Comment: I'm not sure but I expect tellg is failing because you have tried to read past the end of file. Try calling tellg before you call peek not afterwards.

Comment: Alternatively try and simplify. I haven't understood your problem, or read the other answer, but your code does seem very complex.

Comment: @john That's a good point.  Once `file.peek()` returns end of file, `tellg` is invalide, and will fail.  The whole strategy of using multiple passes on an input file in order to parse is broken.

Answer (score 2):

First, *don't* use seek to skip whitespace.  Just get the
character and be done with it.

Second, you seem to misunderstand the meaning of
`istream::good()` and `istream::eof()`.  There is *never*
anytime where `istream::good()` is appropriate, and
`istream::eof()` is usually only appropriate *after* input has
failed.  As for your loop skipping white space, the usual
solution would be:

```
while ( isspace( file.peek() ) && file.peek() != EOF ) {
    file.get();     //  ignore read character...
}
```

Similar comments hold for the other loops as well, except that
you won't want to ignore the read characters.  To collect
characters up to the next `','`, for example:

```
std::string field;
while ( file.peek() != ',' && file.peek() != EOF ) {
    field.push_back( file.get() );
}
```

(And your `file.get( pBuffer, endPos - startPos, ',' || '\n' )`
certainly doesn't do what you expect it to; the expression `','
|| '\n'` will always evaluate to `true`, which, when converted
to a `char`, is `'\01`.)

Finally, while the above strategy will work, it's far preferable
to input larger units of text into an `std::stream`, and parse
that.  If the text is line oriented, use something like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    //  Parse line, using std::istringstream if appropriate,
    //  although this doesn't seem to be the case for your code.
}
```

This is orders of magnitude simpler than what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I think it doesn't help me a lot... 
1.The first code you gave me is almost equal to mine and it doesn't work properly.That file.peek() != EOF fails.
2.Second code actually may help...
3.About my code - I didn't understand you well,but I think it works just fine,cause the problem appear only at the end of the file...
4.And for getline() - that was my second option , but I wanted to understand how can I do this with seekg...it must be some way to do this with this method...
Again - thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: @dragonator `file.peek()` never fails.  If `file.peek()` returns `EOF`, it is either because you are at end of file, or you have already encountered an error of some sort.  And the separate pieces of code are there to explain different errors: once you reach end of file, `file` has failed, and no other operations (including seeking) are valid on it.  As for 3, the end condition for the line I quote is the character `0x01`.  Or you read the exact count: what you probably wanted was `file.read( pBuffer, endPos - startPos )` (but it's still not a good solution).

Comment: @dragonator If the goal is just to get experience with `gseek()`: you probably have to call `file.clear()` immediately before each seek.  Or use C++11 (which specifies that the `eofbit` should be cleared in `seekg`, _before_ anything else).